# NodeJs POST request not working

Tags: javascript, https, request

So lets say I have a URL

```
https://someAPI.com/authorize?x=val1&y=val2
```

Where x and y are the payload values I am sending in
How can i do a post request in this manner?

I have tried this:

```
var https = require('https')

var options = {
    url: 'https://someAPI.com/authorize?x=val1&y=val2',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         ....
    }
}

https.request(options, function(res) {
    var str = ""
    res.on('data', function(data){
        str+=data
    })
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(str)
    })
})
```

I'm not getting anything returned. What am i doing wrong?

Edit: Here is the format I believe:

```
REQUEST
POST https://someAPI.com/us/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=blahblahblah&redirect_uri=someOtherSite.com HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/105.2.3.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: someAPI.com
Content-Length: 98
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

username=someuser&password=somepassword&action=Log%20In&sessionID=someSessionId
```

Comment: Is the missing `'` in `require('https)` a typo in your question or verbatim from your code?

Comment: It's a typo in my post. I'll fix it.

Comment: What about the `url`? Shouldn't it be a `string` too?

Comment: It's hard to tell why *unspecified* API doesn't give you the result you expect from your *obviously abstracted and not real* data. We don't know what it expects you to send.

Comment: This does not look like the current documentation code. Which version of node are you running

Comment: I fixed it. I can't post the real data Quentin, it contains personal information. I am just talking about the format of this post request mainly.

Comment: I believe I am running the most recent release

Comment: @Team.Coco Try to change the first line to `var https = require('request');` if you are using the request npm.

Comment: @Team.Coco — We don't know what format your *unspecified* API expects

Comment: If your callback isn't called, maybe you should try to listen for errors: `req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log('problem with request: '+e.message);
});`

Comment: Are you getting any sort of output or errors?

Comment: You're not finalizing the request with `.end()`

Comment: Okay I added all the info that it says. I'm not sure if that is the format you are referring to or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
https.request(options, function(res) {
    var str = "";
    res.on('data', function(data){
        str+=data;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(str);
    });
});
```

To:

```
var apiCall = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});

apiCall.on("error", (e) => {console.error(e)});
apiCall.end();
```

Comment: Ok cool! That returns the html. With a status code of 500. I know that isn't good, but I assume that has more to do with my credentials than the request. Thank you very much.

Comment: The documentation shows different values being passed for the options. I would have a look at https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback

Comment: Looks like it wants only a URL that is fully encoded (like a connection string) or you pass the values into an object like {port: 443} so it can build the URL

Comment: So, looking at the edit I made above. The last line is the credentials. Are you saying that I should pass those as their own values, sort of like header?

Comment: You can do either, you need to give it the values to make the url or provide the complete url. I prefer the object method because it's less work on my end and easier to edit. Look at this link: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback and you can see the accepted key/values. Looks like there is an AUTH one for you